# Delete hbase cell using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

Is there any api available to delete a specific HBase cell using Spark Scala. We are able to read and write using Spark-HBase Connector. Any suggestion for cell deletion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation for deletion of HBase `Cell` objects, using Spark (I demonstrated it using `parallelize`, you can adjust it to your Cells RDD).

General idea: removal in chunks - iterates through each RDD partition, splitting the partition to chunks of 10,000 Cells, converting each Cell to HBase `Delete` object, then calling `table.delete()` to perform the deletion from HBase.

```
public void deleteCells(List<Cell> cellsToDelete) {

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();

    sc.parallelize(cellsToDelete)
        .foreachPartition(cellsIterator -> {
            int chunkSize = 100000; // Will contact HBase only once per 100,000 records

            org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "YOUR-ZOOKEEPER-HOSTNAME");

            Table table;

            try {
                Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
                table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(config.get("YOUR-HBASE-TABLE")));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                logger.error("Failed to connect to HBase due to inner exception: " + e);

                return;
            }

            // Split the given cells iterator to chunks
            Iterators.partition(cellsIterator, chunkSize)
                .forEachRemaining(cellsChunk -> {
                    List<Delete> deletions = Lists.newArrayList(cellsChunk
                            .stream()
                            .map(cell -> new Delete(cell.getRowArray(), cell.getRowOffset(), cell.getRowLength())
                                    .addColumn(cell.getFamily(), cell.getQualifier(), System.currentTimeMillis()))
                            .iterator());

                    try {
                        table.delete(deletions);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Failed to delete a chunk due to inner exception: " + e);
                    }
                });

        });
}
```

Disclaimer: this exact snippet was not tested, but I have used the same method for removal of billions of HBase Cells using Spark.

Comment: Thank you !! I will try the same in scala.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to try it.I tried the below code in scala which executes without any error,however does not delete any data.I am wondering what did I miss.  `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
val table = new HTable(conf, "mytable");
val delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(1));
delete.deleteColumn(Bytes.toBytes("mycf"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));
table.delete(delete);`

Comment: Try to perform a Get action and see if you can retrieve the cells from HBase.

Comment: The Get operation works fine, I tried the below code. `val  g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
val  result = table.get(g);
val value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("mycf"),Bytes.toBytes("name"));
val name = Bytes.toString(value);
` The data in my table is as below hbase(main):001:0> scan 'mytable'
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
 1                                          column=mycf:name, timestamp=1460540729352, value=Name1
 1                                          column=mycf:prg, timestamp=1460540729352, value=1

Comment: Good. Did you provide a timestamp when performed the Delete?

Comment: I tried with below code for providing the timestamp, Still I get the same result.  I am executing the code through spark-shell with cdh 5.5. I hope there will no issues with that. `val delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(1));
delete.deleteColumn(Bytes.toBytes("mycf"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),1460540729352l);
table.delete(delete);`

Comment: And the value still exists if you perform a Get? Weird.. Looks ok.

Comment: I am able to delete the table but not the row or cells. :)

Comment: And if you try to delete the entire row?

Comment: I tried with `val delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(1));table.delete(delete)` as well as `val delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(1),1460540729352l);table.delete(delete)` , but still no luck with deleting the row.

Comment: Finally I am able to delete the cell and rows. Added the below code for cell deletion.  `val marker = new KeyValue(rowKey, family, Bytes.toBytes("name"),
        HConstants.LATEST_TIMESTAMP, KeyValue.Type.DeleteColumn);
table.delete(new Delete(rowKey).addDeleteMarker(marker));`  Thanks a lot for all the help. :)